# get classOf[Array[A]] from classOf[A]

Tags: arrays, scala

I have a list of scala classes in the form like:

```
List(classOf[A], classOf[B], ...)
```

I need to register these classes as well as the array of the classes into kryo. The result is like:

```
kryo.register(classOf[A]) 
kryo.register(classOf[Array[A]])
kryo.register(classOf[B]) 
kryo.register(classOf[Array[B]])
...
```

So, with the list at hand, I may just use a foreach to register both the class and the array of the class.

However, I fail to get classOf[Array[A]] from classOf[A]. I have tried the ClassTag as following method:

```
def getArrayClass[T: ClassTag](c: Class[T]): Class[_] = {
  classOf[Array[T]]
}
```

The result is not the right (though the type of the both results is the same), and kryo still complains that Class is not registered: A[].

```
scala> getArrayClass(classOf[A])
res0: Class[Array[A]] = class java.lang.Object

scala> classOf[Array[A]]
res1: Class[Array[A]] = class [LA;
```

Any clues? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using the [`wrap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.reflect.ClassTag@wrap:scala.reflect.ClassTag[Array[T]]) method `ClassTag`:

```
def getArrayClass(c: Class[_]): Class[_] =
  scala.reflect.ClassTag(c).wrap.runtimeClass
```

Note that this does not work if `c` is `classOf[Null]` or `classOf[Nothing]` (I believe this is bug in ClassTags). For any other `Class`, it will work.

You can also go to the Java way of doing it, without `ClassTag`s, which is basically equivalent:

```
def getArrayClass(c: Class[_]): Class[_] =
  java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(c, 0).getClass
```